# How can I underline a lot of empty space?

Tags: spacing

I want to do something like `Name: \underline{Bob \hfill}` although that does not work.

I want to be able to have a big underlined empty space with some text in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [**`ulem` package**](http://ctan.asis.io/macros/latex/contrib/ulem/ulem.pdf) which provides various types of underlining that can stretch between words and be broken across lines. Its `\uline` command can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document} 

Name: \uline{Bob Family Name \hfill}

\end{document}
```

which outputs:

[image]

As you can see, the long underline is a bit ugly, in this case, you can just use some reasonable `\hspace` like this:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\begin{document} 

Name: \uline{Bob Family Name\hspace{5em}}

\end{document}
```

with a better output:

[image]

Comment: \newcommand{\lowline}{\uline{\, \hfill \,}} works better